# Issue debugging angular2/karma tests from my IDE: breakpoints are never hit

Tags: intellij-idea, webpack, karma-runner, angular-cli

I am trying to debug my angular2 karma tests from IntelliJ to no avail. I even tried disabling code coverage.

Breakpoints in my tests are never hit.

Here is my karma configuration:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '..',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    customLaunchers: {
      // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
      Chrome_travis_ci: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },
    files: [
      {pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false}
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: { 'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx'] },
    remapIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: {
        html: 'coverage',
        lcovonly: './coverage/coverage.lcov'
      }
    },
    angularCli: {
      config: './angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

The app is built by angular cli (which itself relies on webpack).

Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What cli version do you use? The problem is likely caused by sourcemap defaults change introduced in v1.0.0-beta.21: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/compare/v1.0.0-beta.20-1...v1.0.0-beta.21.

v1.0.0-beta.20-1:

`devtool: 'inline-source-map'`

v1.0.0-beta.21

`devtool: testConfig.sourcemap ? 'inline-source-map' : 'eval',`

This issue can be fixed locally by adding `"sourcemap: true"` in karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    ...
    angularCli: {
      config: './angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev',
      sourcemap: true
    }
    ...
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try out the solution you advised as soon as I return to my computer and reply here accordingly. Please bear with me...

Comment: Thanks a lot! This saved my day!